# $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f \ d\phi$ exists if $f(x)$ is continuous, $\phi$ of bounded variation

Tags: bounded-variation, stieltjes-integral

Let $f$ continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$, $\phi$ of bounded variation on $(-\infty,\infty)$, and $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\ f(x)=0$ then the following Riemann-Stieltjes integral exists:   $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f \ d\phi$$

A function $\phi$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ if $\Gamma$ partition of $[a,b]$ and $\sup_\Gamma \sum_{i=0}^m |\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})|=V(\phi;a,b)<\infty$ or equivalently if there is two increasing functions such that $\phi=\phi_1-\phi_2$. The $V(\phi, -\infty,\infty)=\lim_{a\to-\infty,b\to\infty}V(\phi;a,b)$.

**Exercise 2.17 Measure and integral Intro to Real Analysis Wheeden & Zygmund**

**My proof:** One may assume that $\phi$ is non decreasing. Let $\varepsilon>0$. For any $M>0$, the integral $\int_{-M}^{M}f \ d\phi$ exists, so it's enough to show there is $N>0$ such that for any $x>N$, the integral $\left|\int_N^x f d\phi\right|<\varepsilon$ and for any $x<-N$, the integral $\left|\int_{x}^{-N} f d\phi\right|<\varepsilon$.

Let's see the first: There is $M>0$ such that if $y>M$ then $|f(y)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{V(\phi;-\infty,\infty)}$ assumming the variation of $\phi$ is not $0$. Then picking $N=M+1$ by the mean-value theorem there is $\xi\in[M+1,x]$ such that $$0\leq \left|\int_{M+1}^x f d\phi\right|=\left|f(\xi)(\phi(x)-\phi(M+1))  \right|\leq \left|f(\xi)\right| \left|(\phi(x)-\phi(M+1))  \right|<\varepsilon $$
Therefore $\int_{M+1}^\infty f d\phi=0$. Similarly one can see $\int_{-\infty}^{-M-1} f d\phi=0$. So it exists $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\ d\phi=\int_{-M-1}^{M+1} f\ d\phi$$

I think this proof works (if not please let me known), the sandwich did the work.

**Questions starts here**

I have 2 questions:

**(1)** The reason for $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}f(x)=0$ to be needed, and couldn't be relaxed to $$\lim_{|x|\to \infty}f(x)=a$$ is because we get, for $h=\sup_{\mathbb{R}}{|f(x)|}$ $$0\leq \left|\int_{M+1}^x f d\phi\right|\leq h V(\phi,-\infty,\infty)$$
so no sandwich can be apply. It should leads to some argument to prove its divergence.

**(2)** Is there a proof without using the mean value theorem, using for example upper and lower sums, to prove that $0\leq U_\Gamma-L_\Gamma<\varepsilon $ or for example using Cauchy condition $|R_\Gamma-R_{\Gamma'}|<\varepsilon$ for any $|\Gamma,\Gamma'|<\delta$. If so, how to approach in this infinite improper case?

In this context $$R_\Gamma = \sum_{i=1}^m f(\xi_i)(\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})),\  \ $$ $$ U_\Gamma=\sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}f \right)(\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1}))\  \mathrm{and}\  L_\Gamma = \sum_{i=1}^m\left(\inf_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}f \right)(\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1}))$$ so assuming $\phi$ increasing,  $$L_\Gamma\leq R_\Gamma\leq U_\Gamma$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused: if $\phi$ is globally BV (not just locally BV), then $\int f d\phi$ should be finite if $f$ is just bounded, which would follow from $f$ being continuous and satisfying $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = a$ with $a \neq 0$. Did you maybe mean $\phi$ is just locally BV?

Comment: @Ian Yes, I thinks $|\int_{-\infty}^\infty f d\phi | \leq sup_{\mathbb{R}}|f|V(\phi,-\infty,\infty)<\infty$ but it means that if exists then it should be its bound.

Comment: Right, if the total variation of $\phi$ is finite then you have $\int f d \phi \leq \| f \|_\infty \| \phi \|_{TV}$ which would also answer your second question.

Comment: @Ian I'm wondering if this is enough, because it could happen that something is bounded, but indeed not exists.

Comment: If $\phi$ is globally BV then this is enough. Given how this exercise is stated, I suspect your definition of "BV on $(-\infty,\infty)$" means "locally BV".

Comment: @Ian I think so, because this is the first touch with this theory. I have updated the reference: Exercise 2.17 Measure and integral Intro to Real Analysis Wheeden & Zygmund.